# data.table: Check if all rows are NA by key

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to drop entities in my `data.table` if all entries on a particular column are `NA`. Consider the data below:

```
dfX = data.table(read.table(textConnection(
  "id, t, value
  1, 1, 10 
  1, 2,NA
  2, 1,NA
  2, 2,NA"
), header = TRUE, sep = ","))
is.na(dfX$value)
```

Here, I would like to remove all rows for `id ==2`, but not for `id==1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
dfX[, .SD[!all(is.na(value))], id]
```

Or

```
dfX[dfX[, .I[!all(is.na(value))], id]$V1]
```

Comment: @fgnu `.I` may be a bit faster compared to `.SD`

Comment: Ok, will test that as well.

Comment: Similarly, one could set the key to `id` and select based on that: `setkey(dfX,id); dfX[J(dfX[,!all(is.na(value)),by=id][(V1)]$id)]`

Comment: @Frank Thanks, I guess this will be faster for successive runs,